# php mvc - share methods between models

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, dry

Let's say I have a method in Model A that returns the username from the database, now I want in Model B to also have this method.

What is the best way to do this without repeating myself?

Comment: `class B extends A { }` sounds the more reasonable answer without a context.

Comment: My model is already extending the base model.

Comment: Ok, but... then if the method is the same, the code would be ok. If you just have to change the return slightly you can get the return of the parent and arrange / treat it as you would like. As I said without a context or more explanation of the exact scenario it is hard to tell.

Comment: Make a one line method in Model B that calls the method in Model A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
class ModelB {

    public function method(){
        $object = new ModelA();
        return call_user_func_array(array(&$object, 'method'), func_get_args());
    }

}
```

I didn't just extend ModelA because they could have 'different functions' depending on your context.